# Converting Multiple Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would I convert rows into columns? In this case, taking the columns of `Reason` and `Weight` and expanding the values where more columns are created?

The column `Reason` will only have four values (whereas the field may be blank too): Natural, Emissions, and Humans.

Input Table Example:

```
Location Year   Climate Reason       Weight
USA      2010   Warm    Natural      50.00
USA      2010   Hot     Emissions     0.00
USA      2009   Warm                 20.00
USA      2010   Warm    Humans       30.00
Brazil   2010   Warm    Emissions   100.00
```

Output Table Example

```
Location Year   Climate Natural_Weight Emissions_Weight Humans_Weight NULL_Weight
USA      2010   Warm    50.00            0.00           30.00
USA      2010   Hot
USA      2009   Warm                                                  20.00
Brazil   2010   Warm                   100.00
```

I was thinking of doing a pivot, but got a bit confused since I'm trying to deal with two columns that are dependent on others.

```
SELECT Location, Year, Climate, Natural_Weight, Emissions_Weight, Humans_Weight, NULL_Weight
FROM   (SELECT Location, Year, Climate, Reason, Weight FROM   Test) src
       PIVOT ( Max (Year)
             FOR Climate IN (Location, Year, Climate)) pvt;
```

I tried to do a pivot, but I my above query in generating some horrible errors - at the same time, not sure if I'm missing a group by to ensure things are consolidating in the right way. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help

```
Select *
 From  ( 
            Select Location
                  ,Year
                  ,Climate
                  ,Item = concat(coalesce(Reason,'NULL'),'_Weight')
                  ,Value = Weight
             From YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(Value) for Item in ( [Natural_Weight],[Emissions_Weight],[Humans_Weight],[NULL_Weight] ) ) pvt
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! One question, if I had additional columns (other than Location, Year, and Climate) that help make the row even more unique, how would I add those additional columns?

Comment: @Logan Always happy to help.  Just add the columns in the sub-query.   You must "FEED" the pivot with only the required columns.